# What is the difference between 気が向く and 気がする?

Tags: meaning, usage, pragmatics

Is there any difference in usage between **気{き}が向{む}く** and **気がする**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both can be translated as "feel like", but they are totally different.

`気が向く` is "to feel like doing it", describing someone's volition or intention.

> - 気が向いたら読んでください。 Please read it if you like to.
> - うーん、どうも気が向かない。 Hmm, somehow I don't feel like doing it.

`Verb/adjective + 気がする` is "to feel ～", describing someone's sense or intuition.

> - 難しい本のような気がする。 I feel it's a difficult book.
> - 何かが足りない気がします。 I feel like something is lacking.

**EDIT:** 気がする can also mean "feel like doing", especially in negative sentences.

> - 食べる気がしない。 I don't feel like eating it.

Comment: Can 気がしない be used to express "I don't feel like doing something"? E.g. 外出をする気がしない。

Comment: @user1602 Good point, 気がしない is almost the same as 気が向かない.